# How do i fix my update quantity in my cart page?

Tags: php

These are the codes from my cart page. If I update the quantity the total price is multiplying but not adding or subtracting.

```
<tr align="center">
    <td> <button name="remove[]" onclick="returnshow_confirm();" value="<?php echo $prod_id; ?>">Remove </button></td>
    <td><?php   echo $prod_name; ?><br /> <img src="images/<?php echo $prod_image; ?>" width="60" height="60" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="4" name = "qty" value = "" /></td>

    <-- here are the part of update--->
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['qty'])){
            $asd = $_POST['qty'];
            $update_qty = "update cart set qty = '$asd'";
            $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);
            $_SESSION['qty'] = $qty;
            $total = $total*$qty;           
            echo "<script>windows.open('cart.php',_self)</script>";
        }
        <--- to here --->
    ?>

    <td><?php echo "Php ".$single_price;  ?></td>        
</tr>*/
```

Comment: Adding or substracting what? what is supposed to work?

Comment: The quantity of the product. that the user ordered from the products page. if the customer want to change the quantity. it will either add or subtract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you havn't declared  $qty but assigning in session e-g $_SESSION['qty'] = $qty;
you should try   $_SESSION['qty'] =$asd;

Comment: Okay I'll try. Thank you.

Comment: @michael  also change $total = $total*$qty to  $total = $total*$asd;

Comment: It's already working now. Thank you very much. I really appreciated your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

on which line you are getting error and change this line
$check_pro = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip' AND p_id = '$pro_id' 
to
$check_pro = "select * from cart where ip_add='".$ip."' AND p_id = '".$pro_id."'
as in single quotes u cant specify variables it consider it string